# Angular.js template parsing hook

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, controller

I'm wondering if there is a template parsing hook in Angular, that you can use globally or in specific controllers.

What I want to do is to implement a language and device specific (multidimensional) theme loader, that will dynamically grab any ressource link (img-tags, inline-styles) and redirect to the specific resource.

For example: 
Someone implemented a template that shows some image:

```
<img src="images/my-super-image.jpg">
```

Now I want to grab the template and change the ressource to it's language specific correspondant:

```
<img src="theme/en_us/lowres/my-super-image.jpg">
```

The following things are important for me:

- The one who generates the template doesn't need to take care of the themes, just uses the ressource as given in the first example
- I don't want to use a directive, I want a global (App specific) solution --> best would be to have it in the run()-function of the app
- I don't want to use look-up tables for the ressources, just want it to be highly dynamical

At the moment I'm not quite sure where to place such a parse-hook-function, nor how to get access to the current templates used on a page, to manipulate them before Angular provides them to the DOM.

I used some dirty hack, but I'm unhappy with it, because it will only be applied, when templates are already rendered and provided:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {

  if(angular.isDefined(event.originalEvent.originalTarget.innerHTML)) {
    event.originalEvent.originalTarget.innerHTML = String(event.originalEvent.originalTarget.innerHTML).replace('src="images','src="' + imgPath);
  }
});
```

Do you have any idea of how to do it? Thank you, guys!

Btw. I'm pretty new to Angular, so if you'd please be very descriptive, that would be kind. Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe you could dig into the `$templateCache` (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) somehow? I assume a theme is selected at some point, so perhaps you could programmatically change the templates at that point? That would require pre-loading the `$templateCache` instead of relying on HTTP GET to fetch templates, which in itself is a good thing.

Comment: Ok, but as far as I understand the TemplateCache only caches the template, but is out of the running scope, which means, that if you have a template in TemplateCache it is already provided to the DOM. I would again be behind the DOM injection. Right?

Comment: I would need it as:
1.) Angular loads template
2.) Hook: I grab & edit the template and give it back to Angular
3.) Angular injects the template to DOM

Comment: The whole hook thing is what I am not sure exists. The templateCache works exactly like it sounds, if a given template exists in the cache it is used from the cache. And you can override the templates that are in it. The only other solution I could think of is to create a directive and mess with the template in the compile-function but that would require adding that directive everywhere templates are used and you already stated you didn't want that kind of solution.

Comment: And how can I watch, if a template is added to the $templateCache?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how and where to put in my code?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use compile, Since angular only allow directives to modify DOM you need to create a directive
Here is an example

```
app.directive('myApp', function() {
return {
restrict: 'A',
replace: true,
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

},
compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
tElement.find('img')[0]['src'] = "theme/en_us/lowres/" + tElement.find('img')[0]       ['src'].split('/')[tElement.find('img')[0]['src'].split('/').length - 1];
 }
 };
 });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4VfVuxH8LYLTWHlhUeJK?p=preview)